# Google Books API to find Book Edition

Tags: html, json, api

I'm trying to get the Google Books API to return the Book Edition number. IE: 3rd Edition, 7th, Illustrated, ect.

Using the following code, I can basically get everything I could ever want to find out about the book by changing or adding a few objectType changes. EXCEPT the edition type.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Books API Example</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <script>
     function handleResponse(response) {
     for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
       var item = response.items[i];
       // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
       document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title + " : " + item.volumeInfo.subtitle
    + "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.authors + " "
    + "<br>" + "<img src='" + item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + "'> <br>";
  }
}
</script>
   <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:1435497783&callback=handleResponse"></script>
 </body>
```

Here are the parameters
https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes

Anyone know anything about the edition for the volume?
EDIT:
Also, would anyone be willing to show me how I can do basically an 'if' statement for a subtitle. If the book has one, I want to display it. But if it doesn't, I dont want undefined sitting next to the title.

Comment: To not display subtitle if it is `undefined` you might use something like `item.volumeInfo.title + (item.volumeInfo.subtitle ? ': ' + item.volumeInfo.subtitle : '')`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the API exposes this information, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this since I'm working on using the API myself. The response comes in the form of a JSON object. Take a look at the response and create the requisite classes in the language of your choice. I am using C# and so I used json2csharp.com to create the classes for me. Once you've got that, you can serialize the response into your class(es) which should easily allow you to see which volume(s) returned have a subtitle or any other property your looking form.

Note, that I am performing a web request from the server side when using the API. This is because I have much more flexibility in dealing with the response on the server vs. whipping up some nifty javascript to work in the clients browser (that and my c# skills are much stronger than my JS skills ;-) )